# Color stamping dates for multiple scatter plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have 3 dataframes that have 3 features I'd like to map into scatter plots:

```
Date  Energy  Cost
```

I need to create a series of scatter plots that plot Energy and Cost but color coded by the year in the date column.

The dates are in datetime format and go for 4 years and look like:

```
2015-12-30 00:00:00
2016-20-12 00:00:00
etc...
```

I know I can plot `plt.scatter(data[:], data[:].... c=data[:])`

But cannot figure how to properly format it specifically for intervals of time so that each color is different for each of the 4 years.

Comment: If you only have 4 years of data, the easiest way is probably to call plt.scatter 4x, each time with 'color=' with a different color (e.g. color='red', color='green', etc). In the plt.scatter plots, you then only select the specific year for that color.

Comment: What would the range look like? I have it set as `plt.scatter(df.iloc[0:251, 3], df[0:251, 1], c=south_5.iloc[:250], s=35)`  but this gives me a very distorted graph even with the proper ranges from the data using `plt.xlim` for only the first data set and when the second goes through it gives `TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable`.

Comment: I would do something like `plt.scatter(df.loc[df['Date'].year  ==  2015, 3], df.loc[df['Date'].year  ==  2015, 1], c='red', s=35)`  (Not tested)

Comment: You can pass it an array that is of the same length as your data. So just use map to map the year to a color with a dictionary. `df.Date.dt.year.map({2014: 'red', 2015: 'blue', ...})`

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to create a Series that you can pass as the colors.

#### MCVE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
dates = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='12D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates,
                   'Energy': np.random.randint(1, 1000, len(dates)),
                   'Cost': np.random.randint(10000, 15000, len(dates))})
```

#### Code

```
color_d = {2014: 'red', 2015: 'blue', 2016: 'orange', 2017: 'black'}
df.plot.scatter(x='Energy', y='Cost', c=df.Date.dt.year.map(color_d))
```

[image]

---

Or with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df.Energy.values, df.Cost.values, c=df.Date.dt.year.map(color_d))
_ = plt.xlabel('Energy')
_ = plt.ylabel('Cost')
plt.show()
```